# What are the current research trends in recognizing narrative similarity?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, natural-language-understanding

I am currently working on a term paper on the topic of Narrative Similarity, based on Loizos Michael's work "Similarity of Narratives". I am trying to find the latest trends within this field of study for the literature overview in my assignement. However up untill now I wasn't able to find any new work on this particular subject.

I would appreciate any literature recommendation by anyone out there that has worked on this topic or is currently doing so.

Link to Michael's work:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/316280937_Similarity_of_Narratives